# Front matter layout for hardcover

Tags: publishing

**Problem:** I'm publishing my first hardcover print title using a print-on-demand service. The front matter contains a half-title page, a title page, a copyright page, and a preface. It's an art book filled with high-quality photos of original paintings. I'm not sure of the appropriate ordering of the pages in the front matter and placement of blank pages.

**Front matter layout so far:**

Blank (recto)
Blank (verso)
Blank (recto)
Blank (verso)
Half-Title (recto)
Blank (verso)
Title Page (recto)
Copyright (verso)
Blank (recto)
Blank (verso)
Preface (recto)
Blank (verso)
First Page (recto)

**Question:** Is this layout correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common traditional ordering of the front matter and its elements are listed in the Wikipedia article on [Book Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design#Front_matter):

1. half title (contains the title of the work in small print)
2. frontispice or blank page
3. title page (contains author, title, year, publisher, translator)
4. copyright page (publishing and copyright information)
5. dedication
6. blank page
7. epigraph
8. blank page
9. table of contents
10. blank page (if the TOC doesn't span multiple pages and doesn't end on a left page)
11. and following pages: maps, foreword, preface and the rest of the book

The numbers in the above list correspond to the page numbers counted from the first page of the book. Odd numbers are right pages (recto), odd numbers are left pages (verso).

The front matter is traditinally numbered in Roman numerals or not at all. The first part of the actual story or treatise is page 1. This may be a page containing the title of a chapter or part, so that the first narrative page is numbered as page 3 (or 5, if there is a part title and a chapter title preceding it).

One (sic) blank sheet (two pages) may appear at the beginning and end of the book as part of the hardcover binding. That is, they are not part of the contents of the book (and not counted as part of the page numbering), but happen because of the way the book block is bound into the cover. This sheet usually has a different quality (thicker) and color of the rest of the book. It may be printed with an illustration that spans the inside of the cover and the cover-facing page of this sheet.

*What I would do* is go to a large enough book store that it has several examples of books in my category and look at what professional publishers do.

Paperback books often contain a summary of the story, author information, a scene from the book and/or a list of other books the author has written as part of the front matter. Hardcover books usually don't, but conventions in your genre may vary, so look at your competitors.

---

*Edit regarding your comments*

I'm currently sitting in a university library. I randomly pulled seven or eight books from the shelf in front of me. Two of them had a preface (German *Vorwort*) immediately after the copyright page:

[image: photograph of two books opened to show a preface immediately after the copyright page]

Comment: It seems my ordering is correct except for possibly extra blank pages inserted.  The question remains about each page as being a recto or verso page.

Comment: @E2R0NS I already answered that part of your question. Look at the page numbering. The odd numbered pages are right pages (recto), the even numbered pages are left pages (verso). I added that explanation to my answer. I thought it was self-evident.

Comment: You were referring to the body, not the front matter, no?  Further, my concern is that I have no dedication, TOC, etcetera, so that following the copyright page it would appear that the layout suggested would have two blank pages (one blank sheet) after the copyright page before the preface.

Comment: The *[body of the book](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchblock)* – link is to the German Wikipedia, the English one doesn't seem to have a page for it – is the block of all the pages that are then bound into the cover, including the front matter, body matter, and back matter. The body of the book is to be distinguished from the *[body matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design#Body_matter)* or *[body text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_text)*.

Comment: If your book doesn't have a dedication or table of content or preface, simply leave out those sheets of paper completely. Do not include blank pages where the dedication, TOC, preface, foreword etc. would have been! Books don't have blank sheets (both the front and back blank) inside the body of the book, except at the end, if the number of pages doesn't divide by the number that fits on the printed sheet (usually 16).

Comment: It does have a preface, as I stated.  A verso copyright page followed by a recto preface is unusual.  That is why I inserted a blank sheet there, and why I am looking for feedback here about it.

Comment: That is only uncommon because it is rare for a hardcover book not to have at least a dedication or table of content. Why don't you include a table of content if your book has different parts? That is what is uncommon. I would not, under any circumstances, insert a blank sheet of paper, with a blank recto and a blank verso, between the copyright page and the beginning of the body matter! I cannot stress this enough. That is not something you find it well-designed books at all. If you desperately need something between the copyright and body matter, insert either a TOC or a dedication or both.

Comment: It does not have different parts, so a TOC is not fitting.  After the copyright page is the preface which is not a part of the body matter; it's part of the front matter.

Comment: I have added a comment to the end of my answer regarding your question about whether a preface might immediately follow the copyright page. I hope this settles your question. — Yes, the preface is part of the front matter. But that is irrelevant to your question. Do not insert blank pages between the copyright page and whatever follows it!